# Font graphics in Python

Tags: python

I am beginner in python and I came across this problem and I am struggling with it. I am supposed to compose a star from character "X" this is the function ***ascii_star(size: int) -> None:***

size is always odd number which is greater than 5

[how the star is supposed to look for size = 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH0lM.jpg)

***this is my code***

import math

def ascii_star(size: int) -> None:

```
x1_placement = 1
x2_placement = math.floor(size/2)+1
x3_placement = size
for j in range (1, size+1):
    if j == math.floor(size/2 + 1):
        for _ in range (1, size+1):
            print("O", end="")
    for i in range (1, size +1):
        if i== x1_placement or i == x2_placement or i == x3_placement:
            print("X", end="")
            continue
        print(" ", end="")
    print()
    x1_placement += 1
    x3_placement -= 1
```

but in the middle line where it is supposed to be just line composed out of X I have a ***problem that one X is pushed to the side.***

[my star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROk49.png)

can someone please tell he how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if j == math.floor(size/2 + 1):` block is responsible for drawing the horizontal line halfway down your image. After this block executes, you go on to execute the `for i in range (1, size +1):` block, which renders the diagonal and vertical lines. But these should be mutually exclusive -- if you print the horizontal line and then the diagonal/vertical lines, they'll be concatenated together and the line will be twice as long as it's supposed to be. That's why you're seeing `OOOOOOO___X___`.

Try putting your `for i in range (1, size +1):` in an `else` block so that it doesn't execute on the row that has a horizontal line.

```
import math
size = 7
x1_placement = 1
x2_placement = math.floor(size/2)+1
x3_placement = size
for j in range (1, size+1):
    if j == math.floor(size/2 + 1):
        for _ in range (1, size+1):
            print("O", end="")
    else:
        for i in range (1, size +1):
            if i== x1_placement or i == x2_placement or i == x3_placement:
                print("X", end="")
                continue
            print(" ", end="")
    print()
    x1_placement += 1
    x3_placement -= 1
```

Result:

```
X  X  X
 X X X
  XXX
OOOOOOO
  XXX
 X X X
X  X  X
```

---

Alternatively, remove your `if j == math.floor(size/2 + 1):` block entirely, and move that conditional inside your `for i in range (1, size +1):` loop. You'll lose the ability to render different characters for different orientations of line, but since that's not explicitly required by your problem statement, maybe it's worth it for the improved concision.

```
import math
size = 7
x1_placement = 1
x2_placement = math.floor(size/2)+1
x3_placement = size
for j in range (1, size+1):
    for i in range (1, size +1):
        if i== x1_placement or i == x2_placement or i == x3_placement or j == math.floor(size/2 + 1):
            print("X", end="")
            continue
        print(" ", end="")
    print()
    x1_placement += 1
    x3_placement -= 1
```

Result:

```
X  X  X
 X X X
  XXX
XXXXXXX
  XXX
 X X X
X  X  X
```